# Whats best practice for file upload validation and file storing in models in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Lets say I have an image field `image` with the following validation rules: `required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg|max:2048` and after successful validation and saving of the model the image gets saved in a directory.

My current approach is that after that the model's `image` field value will be the path to the image, like `storage/images/file.jpg`. This has the following drawback:

When editing the model again and not changing the image (i. e. uploading another image) the request does not contain the `image` field so its requirement rule will fail.

I could only validate its rules when there is an upload present in the request but it feels like I am missing something. Is it generally bad practice to save the path in the file/ upload field? Is there a streamlined way of doing this?

Another approach might be treating each uploaded file as a model and use relationships, but I feel like this is overkill.

Edit: I feel like there could be a Rule "Validate as image when a file is being uploaded" but I guess I have to do that with custom logic.

Comment: what does this mean ?

When editing the model again and not changing the image (i. e. uploading another image) the request does not contain the image field so its requirement rule will fail.

Comment: @KhayamKhan I dont know how else to describe it. When you _update_ an existing model and dont upload a file, that field will be null/ not present in the request when validating the input.

Comment: then you can check if the file is actually present in the request and there is a rule called sometime.

for the best way for the uploading images/files you can create a polymorphic table or can use spatie media package which gives you media table a polymorphic table and all you media from any part of the application will lye there.

Comment: @KhayamKhan I appreciate your efforts, but there are already answers discussing that topic. Thanks though.

Comment: Are you upload and update the image in the same time? If you have define two different routes one for upload and one for update, you should use different rules for each route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there already is a validation Rule to do exactly that. `sometimes`

Your Validation rule would look like this:

```
'image' => 'sometimes|required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg|max:2048'
```

Now the rules will be applied only if the data is present in the request.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-when-present

If you want to only make it required if the model has no path use the Rule Facade

Then you could use the Rule Facade to make a required_if Like so

```
Rule::requiredIf(fn() => !$myModel?->path_to_image)
```

Your Validation should look like that:

```
'image' => ['sometimes', Rule::requiredIf(fn() => !$myModel?->path_to_image), 'image', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg', 'max:2048']
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if

--

To your first question. Its completely fine to save the filepath directly in the database. That way you're also able to use the `asset()` helper without any additional info as the path.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about about `sometimes` but the problem is that would allow for storing new records without an image field. But the field should be required, unless the model already has a file path saved to it (i. e. had had an image uploaded before).

Comment: Then you could use the Rule Facade to make a ```required_if``` Like so ```Rule::requiredIf(fn() => !$myModel?->path_to_image)```
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if